# Dynamic content using .PO file

Tags: php, wordpress, gettext

I have a Wordpress site that has support for other languages using the `gettext` system.

I am curious if I can call content dynamically, let's say from function `the_content()`:

```
printf( __( '%s', 'my-theme' ), the_content() );
```

I'm guessing this is only possible if I provide the entire string in a `.po` file, which would obviously be in-efficient, not to mention that content would always be changing.

But I CAN do this, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Since `the_content()` should be the content of a Post or a Page, you can install WordPress plugin like qTranslate, zTranslate or equiv. to provide multi-language contents.

Translation via `.po` file is only recommend for static contents, like menu items, static links, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Raptor, I actually am aware of all the plugins to do this, I was really more interested in whether it could actually be done, just for peace or mind after days of frustration :)

Comment: Though index keys of `.po` file should be static contents, technically it could be done.

Comment: and the way I would do this is to use `%s` as the index in `POEDIT`, and then I would use entire content from the text editor (i.e. `the_content()`) as the actual translated string?  Is this technically now it could be done?

Comment: No you can't do this with POEDIT